# Dfu-util running 10 times slower on one PC than on another

Tags: embedded, usb, dfu

I am using [Dfu-util](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dfu-util.1.en) to flash firmware onto an [NXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NXP_Semiconductors) device. It all works fine on my Windows 7 64 bit desktop, but on my [Dell Inspiron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron) 6400 laptop, running Windows 10 32 bit (rather well, as it happens), the firmware download takes about ten times as long.

How can I fix this?

Comment: First pointer: This is off-topic here. Maybe try [su] instead.

Comment: Is it the Kinetis (now under NXP)  bootloader using blhost? There is a bug in some versions that causes a 100 ms (or maybe 10, I can't recall) delay between 32 byte packets. You need to get the source, change a constant and recompile if that's the case.

Comment: No,it isn't. But thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @Filburt - no, it is not off topic.  This is a **development tool** question, hence explicitly on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, at least applicable in my case:

Connecting the board directly to the PC resulted in extremely slow DFU speed. However, adding a simple hub (4-port USB 2.0, unpowered) in between immediately made DFU download much faster.

It may be possible that the difference between the two computers was due to one using an internal hub or different USB topology that had the same effect.

As to why this helped, I have no clue, but it did and is perfectly reproducible in my case.

Comment: Yes, different combinations of powered/unpowered, hub/no hub, different USB cables, USB2/USB3 ports, USB2/USB3 capable hubs, different USB ports (incl. in the same USB hub) is worth trying.